# GRASS and r.viewshed

Tags: grass-gis, coordinates, viewshed, grass.script

I'm trying to run the r.viewshed command using co-ordinates held in a .csv file I imported using v.in.ascii. It has over 200 rows and I'm looking to run viewsheds from each line, without doing it manually.

I can't seem to add the coordinates to the r.viewshed command without doing it manually. I'd also like to look at creating a script so I can run them one after the other without much involvement.

My command at the moment is: r.viewshed input=MasterRaster@CotswoldSevern output=BRK11 coordinates=370546.006419,171670.256898

What I would like to try and do is get the co-ordinates out from the .csv

Can anyone help?

Comment: Are you interested in running the grass script under Windows (.bat) or Linux (.sh)?

Comment: I'll be running it on a windows pc.

Comment: You may use the Python shell in the wxGUI (see tab there) in order to write a small loop.